# While loop in Java :: keep dividing while contion is not met

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have a basic code:

```
public class experiment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(experiment(80));
    }

    public static int experiment (int number) {
        while (number > 10) {
            number = number / 2;
            return number;
        } return -1;
    }
}
```

It returns me `40`.

So it means is not looping on the variable `number`.

I would like it to keep looping on `number` (80, 40, 20, 10), till it return `10`.

Is there a way to do it **without using the** `for` **loop**?

Comment: You return the number after the first division; return it after the loop has finished.

Comment: you have a return statement inside your loop.  So it will return on the first iteration. Just remove it and return after your loop has finished. BTW: The same thing wuld happen if you would use a for loop and return inside the for loop. This isn't specific to the while loop

Comment: return number; -> there's your issue, this ends the method, so the loop as well

Comment: `public static int experiment (int number) {
         while (number > 10) {
             number = number / 2;
            
         } return number;
     }`

Comment: oh, I believe it might work. You can post the answer, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `return` out of the loop:

```
public static int experiment (int number) {
    while (number > 10) {
        number = number / 2;
    }
    return number;
}
```

If you need the -1 for a special case, you should check it before entering the loop:

```
public static int experiment (int number) {
    if (number < 0) { // or some condition
        return -1;
    }
    while (number > 10) {
        number = number / 2;
    }
    return number;
}
```

BTW, start using a debugger, you can step through this kind of code and find the problem easily.

Answer (score 0):

What wrong is that you put `return number` inside the `while` loop it will end the iteration and return the value of `40`. So you have to,

```
public static int experiment (int number) {
    while (number > 10) {
        number = number / 2;
    } 
    return number;
}
```

If you want all the numbers the loop has passed to print;

```
public static void experiment (int number) {
    while (number > 10) {
        number = number / 2;
        System.out.println(number);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

using recursion:

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(test.toTen(80));

    }
    public static int toTen(int k) {
        if (k==10) {
            return k;
        }
        else {
            return toTen(k/2);
        }

    }

}
```

or simply edit the loop like so

```
        while (k > 10) {
            k = k / 2;
        } 

        return k;
```

Comment: Why use recursion? If you are saying this is a better approach, you need to explain why. And you need to explain why OP's approach didn't work. Dumping code without explanation does not make a good answer.